# How can I assign a set of values randomly across the column in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and was trying to implement the following task. Given the column **user_id** in a PostgreSQL table, I wish to assign random values to the column **hub_id** in the same table. This hub_id should contain only values available in a list of n numbers - Eg hub_list[25,38,36,300,350].

```
User_id | Hub_id
1        25
2        36
3        25
4        38
```

How to carry out an update statement for this?

I just tried using this code but it showed only one value throughout the column, and unable to get a list of values

```
UPDATE <table name>
SET hub_id = (select floor(random() * 10) + 1)
WHERE a.hub_id = a.hub_id;
```

Comment: What is the intention behind `WHERE a.hub_id = a.hub_id;`?

Comment: `UPDATE a.user_id` statement must require table name i.e. `update tablename` . you are providing column name.

Comment: Why don't you just use `hub_id = random() * 10 + 1;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Using update statement without **where** clause was throwing a dangerous warning. Thus I included a harmless statement to avoid the warning message.

Comment: I have no idea what "dangerous warning" is supposed to me. There certainly is no such warning in core Postgres. And `WHERE a.hub_id = a.hub_id;` is exactly the same as no WHERE clause if `hub_id` is defined as NOT NULL

Comment: @RajPaliwal. Thanks for that, My bad. I intended to use table_name in the Update statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses arrays:

```
UPDATE a.user_id
    SET hub_id = (array[25, 38, 36, 300, 350])[floor(1 + random()*cardinality(array[25, 38, 36, 300, 350]))];
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8bfa0975c80134613701b68de441f65b) is a db<>fiddle.